# How to take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on **Selenium WebDriver, Java** and the **TestNG** framework.

The code I had written in **Java**.

If my Java code is in Boolean, how I can take a screenshot?

Example:

```
public boolean test() throws Exception {
    // Some implementation
}
```

I tried this step, but it is showing an error:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

The error is showing in this line for the copyFile as `The method copyFile(File, File) is undefined for the type FileUtils`:

```
 FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver). Did you really do any searching before posting this question?

Comment: This is the highest voted question in [Selenium FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How can I take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)*

Comment: What do you mean by *"my Java code is in Boolean"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public  class Test {

    public void screenShot() {

        // 'driver' is your WebDriver
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(fileName));

    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order, e.g. what is the intent/idea behind this solution? You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22552491/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample program for this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order, e.g. what is the intent/idea behind this solution? You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22552667/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do, instead of screenshots, to make sure a page looks the way you want it to, is to:

1. Use WebElement.getLocation() to get the coordinates of the element
   or page section.
2. Use WebElement.getSize() to get the dimensions of that element
   or page section.
3. Use WebElement.getText() to verify contents of that element or section.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a Firefox `Driver` object then:

```
    FirefoxDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Driver.get("http://facebook.com/");
    File ScrFile = Driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(ScrFile, new File("D://img.jpg"));
```

Comment: Are capitalised variable names (`Driver` and `ScrFile`) a Java convention?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Shutterbug JAR file from [here](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=selenium-shutterbug&g=com.assertthat&v=0.2&downloadable=1).

```
public void takeSnapShot(String i) throws Exception {

    /* Function: This function is used to take a snapshot. It
                 will take a snapshot of the entire page.

       Function Call: takeSnapShot("Screen_name"); 
    */

    Shutterbug.shootPage(browser, ScrollStrategy.BOTH_DIRECTIONS).save(Path + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert web driver object to the TakeScreenshot
TakesScreenshot scrst = ((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);

// Call getScreenshotAs method to create an image file
File SrcFile = scrst.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Move image file to the new destination
File DestFile = new File(fileWithPath);

// Copy file at the destination
FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);

    File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    File DestFile = new File(fileWithPath);

    FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order, especially when the code seems to be incomplete (e.g., is it a fragment or is it really missing something). Preferably, [edit you answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60669265/edit).